# Author says P is true for n > 2, but I got it for n ≥ 2

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I noticed what is the potential mistake that the author has made, but I doubt myself, even for calcutating 12x16!! Please tell whether my conclusion is correct or how is the author right about their conclusion.

### problem

[image: problem picture]

### Mistake in Book

I think the author concluded wrong that P<sub>n</sub> implies P<sub>n+1</sub> **if n > 2**. The author, by mistake, may have put "=" sign in the last part of solution instead of ">".

*in book*: (n+1)! - 3<sup>n+1</sup> **=** 3<sup>n</sup>(n-2)
*my correction*: (n+1)! - 3<sup>n+1</sup> **>** 3<sup>n</sup>(n-2)

### My approach

Assume P<sub>n</sub> is true for some integer n.
n! - 3<sup>n</sup> > 0
n! > 3<sup>n</sup>
n! . 3 > 3<sup>n+1</sup>
as n! . a ≥ n! . 3, for all integers a ≥ 3
n! . a > 3<sup>n+1</sup>, for all integers a ≥ 3
let n+1 = a
n!(n+1) > 3<sup>n+1</sup>, for all integers n ≥ 2
Therefore, P<sub>n</sub> implies P<sub>n+1</sub> **if n ≥ 2**.

I got that P<sub>n</sub> implies P<sub>n+1</sub> **if n ≥ 2**, but author says the same **for n > 2**

Comment: If $n =2$ then all you can conclude is $(n+1)!-3^{n+1} > 3(n+1) -3^{n-1}$ which would be negative if $n=2$.   We need $n > 2$ in order to assume $ 3(n+1) -3^{n-1}$ is positive.

Comment: I think you are misreading the proof, you should read it all in one line $A=B>C=D$ , and so $A>D$. By setting it the way (s)he does the author has misled you.

Comment: "The author, by mistake, may have put "=" sign in the last part of solution instead of ">"."  No mistake. $3^{n}(n+1) - 3^{n+1} $ does *indeed* equal $3^{n}(n-2)$ (Do the algebra: $3^n(n+1) - 3^{n+1} = 3^{n}(n+1)-3\cdot 3^n = 3^n(n+1-2)= 3^n(n-2)$. )  And *THAT* value is negative if $n \le 2$.  So *IF* $n > 2$ then the induction step is valid.  But if $n \le 2$ the induction step doesn't lead to any valid conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

$P_2$ is the statement $2! - 3^2 > 0$, which is obviously false.

You seem to be misunderstanding that the step occurring immediately after the use of the induction hypothesis,
$$3^n (n+1) - 3^{n+1} = 3^n \left( (n+1) - 3^1\right) = 3^n (n-2)$$
is an *algebraic identity* that is true for all $n$.  It is **not** true that
$$3^n (n+1) - 3^{n+1} > 3^n (n-2).$$

What the author is doing is basically writing a chain of equalities and inequalities to establish that if $P_n$ is true, then $P_{n+1}$ is true.  The result of the overall chain is that of inequality, but some intermediate steps are equalities.  It's like saying, if $n > 0$, then
$$10^n = 2^n \cdot 5^n > 5^n.$$
The first step is equality, and the second is inequality, so overall, $10^n > 5^n$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: But I didn't say algebraic identity is wrong. In the statement (equation) that I pointed out as author's mistake (_in book_ part), the first term of the LHS of equation has (n+1)! instead of 3^(n+1), that's why I called that equation as a mistake.

Comment: @Cinverse You're misinterpreting the notation.  The book never says the equality you claim it says.

Comment: @Cinverse: What you're calling a mistake in the book is, I think, a misread. The author is not claiming that $(n+1)! - 3^{n+1} = 3^n(n-2)$. They are claiming that $(n+1)! - 3^{n+1} > 3^n(n+1) - 3^{n+1}$ (follows from the inductive hypothesis), and since $3^n(n+1) - 3^{n+1} = 3^n(n-2)$ (algebra), that $(n+1)! - 3^{n+1} > 3^n(n-2)$ (by transitivity). Your “correction” is exactly what the author intended.

Comment: okay my bad that I misread it, but still how did they got n > 2 as condition? the term 3^n(n-2) >= 0, right (as the LHS should be compared greater against 0)? so n must be >= 2

Comment: @Cinverse The point is that $n > 2$ is _strong enough_.  We could make it stronger, as you have written by using $n \geq 2$, but we don't get anything important from that.  The earliest base case is $n=7$, which is well within both inequalities.

Comment: $3^n(n-2) > 0$ *IF* $n > 2$.  But if $n \le 2$ then $3^n(n-2) < 0$ and the our induction step fails.  $P(n) \not \implies P(n+1)$ if $n \le 2$.  We can only conclude $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ *ONLY* if $n > 2$

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think you are misreading as well.  $n\ge 2$ is *NOT* strong enough and it could not have been written with $n=2$.  If $n = 2$ or attempt at induction only yields that $(n+1)! - 3^{n+1} > 3^n(n-2)$.  But as $3^n(n-2) \not > 0$ for $n=2$ we can *NOT* conclude $(n+1)! - 3^{n+1} > 0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Maybe n >= 2 is talking about truthness of induction statement: p(n) -> p(n+1). I don't know about these logics, but maybe for some reason p(n) -> p(n+1) doesn't makes sense for n < 2. The preposition (n! - 3^n > 0) maybe wrong for n == 2, but the induction statement is still true for n == 2 (0 -> 1 validates the statement as true, right?)

Comment: @fleablood The proof of the induction step shows $(n+1)! - 3^{n+1} > 3^n(n-2)$.  If $n=2$, the right hand side is $0$, so it becomes $(n+1)! - 3^{n+1} > 0$.  (remember "$F \to F$" is $T$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring if p(n) is false, the statement p(n) -> p(n+1) is still holding true, right? (sorry I couldn't edit my last comment where i wrote 0->1 but I wanted to say this)

Comment: @Cinverse We don't care about $n < 2$.  The _given proof_ of $P_n \to P_{n+1}$ works when $n > 2$.  We can also recognize the same proof works when $n \geq 2$, but the fact that the proof doesn't work when $n < 2$ doesn't mean anything about whether $P_n \to P_{n+1}$ is true or false there (it's true, at least for $n \geq 0$, but the given proof doesn't show us that).  My point is that the interval on which the given proof of the inductive step is valid doesn't matter as long as it includes $n \geq 7$ because $n=7$ is our base case.  In that sense, $n > 2$ is equally as useful as $n\geq 2$.

Comment: @fleablood Alternatively, just note that $a > b \geq 0$ is sufficient to conclude $a > 0$.

Comment: hmmm...... Somehow I was getting that $n-2 < 0$ if $n=2$..... I guess that was a brain fart.  (Maybe I was thinking that $2 = 3$ so $n-2 =n-3 < 0$ or something equally brain farty.)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Okay. I guess the condition n >= 2 is just about what the fundamental property I used to arrive at that inequality can gurantee . So, basic assumption is n! > 3^n. I made a >= 3 & inequality as n!.a > 3 ^ (n+1). I used the property (a > b implies ac > bc, c > 0) to get it, so it gurantees inequality's truth as long as a >= 3 or n >= 2 (I took n+1 = a, so n >= 2). n < 2 doesn't mean n! x a > 3 ^ (n+1) doesn't hold, it just mean the property I used can't gurantee the truthness anymore. (just like if a > b, 2a > 3b cant be guranteed by this property)

Answer (score 3):

Let $Q_n$ be the statement $P_n \implies P_{n+1}$. The author says $Q_n$ holds for $n \gt 2$ and you say that it holds for $n \geq 2$.

You are giving a stronger statement. You only need to see the case of $P_2 \implies P_3$. But that is a false implies anything statement. So you are fine with saying $Q_n$ holds for $n \geq 2$.

It is just unhelpful. In order to get to the base case for the induction, you have to go up to $n = 7$ anyway. Similarly for all the $Q_2 \cdots Q_6$.

All you need to agree on is that you get something stronger than $\forall n \geq 7, Q_n$.

Comment: I just want to know whether I did any mistake in any argument. I agree that it doesn't matter whether n>2 or n>3 as 7 is the first n where  preposition is true. But maybe (its just my thought) it is still important because we are saying that the induction, i.e., p(n) implies p(n+1), is true for n >= 2, but not the preposition, i.e., n! - 3^n > 0. the induction statement and preposition are different. even for n == 2, the preposition maybe wrong, but the induction statement is true because it says p(n+1) is true if p(n) is true, as p(2) is false, its like 0 -> 1 (whose truth value is 1 right?).

Comment: correction to previous comment: p(n) -> p(n+1) is true even if p(n) is false, right? (ignore previous comment's 0->1 argument, instead read this)